# Django list_filter query set return, ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django

i'm constructing a self filter in site admin app django, for a users that contains in an array field a value in especified. but i'm couldn't implement  cause return error.

this is my model:

```
class Profile(Model):
"""
Profile
"""
code = CharField(
    max_length = 32,
    verbose_name = (_(u"Código")),
    blank = True,
)
user = ForeignKey(User,
    verbose_name = (_('Usuario')),
    related_name = 'profile',
    blank = False,
    unique = True,
)
country = CountryField(
    verbose_name = (_(u"País")),
    blank = False,
    default = 'CO',
)
preferences = CharField(
    max_length = 500,
    verbose_name = (_(u"Preferencias")),
    blank = True,
)
etc...
```

this is my admin registeer for that model:

```
class ProfileAdmin(ExportMixin, ModelAdmin):

list_display = (
    'id',
    'user',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'country',
    'isTeacher',
    'purchased',
    'purchasedDetails',
    'referred',
    'moneySpent',
    'likesCount',
    'created',
    'preferences',
)

list_filter = (
    'country',
    'referred',
    PreferencesFilter,
)

search_fields = (
    'user__username',
    'user__first_name',
    'user__last_name',
)
site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

where PreferencesFilter funtion is:

```
class PreferencesFilter(SimpleListFilter):
title = _('Preferencias')
parameter_name = 'preferencias'

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return [PREFERENCES1 + PREFERENCES2]

def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    if not self.value():
        return queryset


    return queryset.filter(preferences__contains=[self.value()])
```

the values for PREFERENCES1 and PREFERENCES2 are:

```
PREFERENCES1 = (
   ('Croché', 'Croché'),
   ('Patchwork', 'Patchwork'),
   ('Muñecos decorativos', 'Muñecos decorativos'),
   ('Tejido dos agujas', 'Tejido dos agujas')
)

PREFERENCES2 = (
   ('Arreglos florales', 'Arreglos florales'),
   ('Peinados', 'Peinados'),
   ('Decoración de uñas', 'Decoración de uñas')
)
```

but when i make a search with that filter the app return this stacktrace:

```
 Template error:
 In template /env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suit/templates/admin/search_form.html, error at line 17
  too many values to unpack
   7 :         {% if cl.search_fields %}
   8 :           <input type="text" size="40" name="{{ search_var }}" value="{{ cl.query }}" id="searchbar" placeholder="{% block search_placeholder %}{% trans 'keyword'|capfirst %}{% endblock %}"{{ cl.query|yesno:' class=active,' }}>&nbsp;
   9 :           <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("searchbar").focus();</script>
   10 :         {% endif %}
   11 :         {% spaceless %}
   12 :           {% if cl.has_filters %}
   13 :             {% block filters %}
   14 :               {% if cl.has_filters %}
   15 :                 <span class="search-filters">
   16 :                 {% for spec in cl.filter_specs %}
   17 :                    {% suit_list_filter_select cl spec %} 
   18 :                   &nbsp;
   19 :                 {% endfor %}
   20 :                 </span>
   21 :               {% endif %}
   22 :             {% endblock %}
   23 :           {% endif %}
   24 :         {% endspaceless %}
   25 : 
   26 :         <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Search' %}" class="btn btn-info"/>
   27 :         &nbsp;

Traceback:
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
137. response = response.render()
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
105. self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
82. content = template.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
140. return self._render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
134. return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
 123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
 78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/kperez/Desarrollo/www.pleisi.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
 123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
 134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
1220.                     return self.nodelist.render(new_context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
389. return strip_spaces_between_tags(self.nodelist.render(context).strip())
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
53.             result = self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
305.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
78.             return node.render(context)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
196.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
1125.                     return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suit/templatetags/suit_list.py" in suit_list_filter_select
113.     choices = list(spec.choices(cl))
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py" in choices
103.         for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:

Exception Type: ValueError at /site/accounts/profile/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

What i'm doing bad, or what should i do for solve this trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used custom filter, but my guess is the line

```
 return queryset.filter(preferences__contains=[self.value()])
```

is causing the problem

contains should be a single value, not an array.
Did you try?

```
return queryset.filter(preferences__contains=self.value())
```

Edit:

Ok , I see the problem now:

You are trying to append two tuples to get a list. Tuples are imutable, and the syntax you are using isn't going to concatenate them to a list.

change lookups to :

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):

    newlist = list(PREFERENCES1)
    newlist.extend( list(PREFERENCES2)) 
    return newlist
```

Comment: y try, but now every time that chose that model in the admin crash with that error

Comment: lookups is supposed to return a list of tuples, you are returning a list with one value. in lookups try something like  return [(PREFERENCES1, PREFERENCES1) + (PREFERENCES2, PREFEERENCES2))]

Comment: yes same error both ways.. i forgot set that PREFERENCES1 PREFERENCES2 was in this way  PREFERENCES1 = (
    ('Croché', 'Croché'),
    ('Patchwork', 'Patchwork'),
    ('Muñecos decorativos', 'Muñecos decorativos'),
    ('Tejido dos agujas', 'Tejido dos agujas')
)

PREFERENCES2 = (
    ('Arreglos florales', 'Arreglos florales'),
    ('Peinados', 'Peinados'),
    ('Decoración de uñas', 'Decoración de uñas')
)

Comment: You will need to post that part of the code, as that's where it seems to be going wrong. Sure you haven't added and extra entry into one of the tuples? That would explain the error.